# How to change Mathematica icon on Windows Start Screen

Tags: windows

How to change Mathematica icon in Windows Start Screen? In the Menu Start it is red, but in Start Screen is white:

[image]

And changing the icon via Properties -> Shortcut -> change icon helps only in Menu Start, not Start Screen

[image]

Is there any opportunity to change it? I'm used to red icon and I often confuse it with other.

Comment: This is more of a Windows question than a Mathematica question - that being said, you can try the [TileIconifier](https://github.com/Jonno12345/TileIconifier/releases) application